# Hide WYSIWYG editor on certain templates

Tags: functions, wysiwyg

I hope the title makes sense. I currently want to hide the default WYSIWYG editor on some of the pages but display it on others.

Is there a filter or a hook for the functions file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right.

The following code will remove the editor from the pages using particular templates:

```
<?php

function wpse242371_remove_editor_from_some_pages()
{
    global $post;

    if( ! is_a($post, 'WP_Post') ) {
        return;
    }


    /* basename is used for templates that are in the subdirectory of the theme */
    $current_page_template_slug = basename( get_page_template_slug($post_id) );

    /* file names of templates to remove the editor on */
    $excluded_template_slugs = array(
        'tmp_file_one.php',
        'tmp_file_two.php',
        'tmp_file_three.php'
    );

    if( in_array($current_page_template_slug, $excluded_template_slugs) ) {
        /* remove editor from pages */
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
        /* if needed, add posts or CPTs to remove the editor on */
        // remove_post_type_support('post', 'editor');
        // remove_post_type_support('movies', 'editor');
    }

}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse242371_remove_editor_from_some_pages');
```

Comment: I think that is exactly what I'm looking for... Thanks!!
`remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');` didn't know this was a thing

Answer (score 0):

```
remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
```

You can use it in several ways, a checkbox in the page would be nice, which if checked will hide the editor.

For more info > https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support